# WooCommerce - wc_get_products() not returning images and categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

The WooCommerce method `wc_get_products()` is not returning images and categories as objects. They only return an ID. Is there a way to let `woocommerce` return the full images and categories? The REST API does return the full image but the internal method does not.
See example

#### When calling the rest API

```json
"categories": [
            {
                "id": 123,
                "name": "Name of category",
                "slug": "Slug of category"
            },
            {
                "id": 124,
                "name": "Name of category",
                "slug": "Slug of category"
            }
        ],
"images": [
            {
                "id": 12345,
                "date_created": "2021-02-10T15:52:32",
                "date_created_gmt": "2021-02-10T13:52:32",
                "date_modified": "2021-02-10T15:53:06",
                "date_modified_gmt": "2021-02-10T13:53:06",
                "src": "https://websitename.com/wp-content/uploads/imagename.jpeg",
                "name": "Name of image",
                "alt": "Alternative image text"
            }
        ],
```

#### When calling the `wc_get_products()`

```json
"category_ids": [
            114,
            118,
            270,
            239
        ],
"image_id": "1881",
        "gallery_image_ids": [
            1882
        ],
```

Why do they do this? And is there a way to return the full objects?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The categories and images are listed in API by using the below lines of codes.

```
'categories'         => wc_get_object_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat', 'name' ),
'images'             => $this->get_images( $product ),
```

The product data returns in API by using the below function.`/woocommerce/includes/legacy/api/v3/class-wc-api-products.php`

```
   /**
     * Get standard product data that applies to every product type
     *
     * @since 2.1
     * @param WC_Product|int $product
     * @return array
     */
    private function get_product_data( $product ) {
        if ( is_numeric( $product ) ) {
            $product = wc_get_product( $product );
        }

        if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
            return array();
        }

        $prices_precision = wc_get_price_decimals();
        return array(
            'title'              => $product->get_name(),
            'id'                 => $product->get_id(),
            'created_at'         => $this->server->format_datetime( $product->get_date_created(), false, true ),
            'updated_at'         => $this->server->format_datetime( $product->get_date_modified(), false, true ),
            'type'               => $product->get_type(),
            'status'             => $product->get_status(),
            'downloadable'       => $product->is_downloadable(),
            'virtual'            => $product->is_virtual(),
            'permalink'          => $product->get_permalink(),
            'sku'                => $product->get_sku(),
            'price'              => wc_format_decimal( $product->get_price(), $prices_precision ),
            'regular_price'      => wc_format_decimal( $product->get_regular_price(), $prices_precision ),
            'sale_price'         => $product->get_sale_price() ? wc_format_decimal( $product->get_sale_price(), $prices_precision ) : null,
            'price_html'         => $product->get_price_html(),
            'taxable'            => $product->is_taxable(),
            'tax_status'         => $product->get_tax_status(),
            'tax_class'          => $product->get_tax_class(),
            'managing_stock'     => $product->managing_stock(),
            'stock_quantity'     => $product->get_stock_quantity(),
            'in_stock'           => $product->is_in_stock(),
            'backorders_allowed' => $product->backorders_allowed(),
            'backordered'        => $product->is_on_backorder(),
            'sold_individually'  => $product->is_sold_individually(),
            'purchaseable'       => $product->is_purchasable(),
            'featured'           => $product->is_featured(),
            'visible'            => $product->is_visible(),
            'catalog_visibility' => $product->get_catalog_visibility(),
            'on_sale'            => $product->is_on_sale(),
            'product_url'        => $product->is_type( 'external' ) ? $product->get_product_url() : '',
            'button_text'        => $product->is_type( 'external' ) ? $product->get_button_text() : '',
            'weight'             => $product->get_weight() ? wc_format_decimal( $product->get_weight(), 2 ) : null,
            'dimensions'         => array(
                'length' => $product->get_length(),
                'width'  => $product->get_width(),
                'height' => $product->get_height(),
                'unit'   => get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' ),
            ),
            'shipping_required'  => $product->needs_shipping(),
            'shipping_taxable'   => $product->is_shipping_taxable(),
            'shipping_class'     => $product->get_shipping_class(),
            'shipping_class_id'  => ( 0 !== $product->get_shipping_class_id() ) ? $product->get_shipping_class_id() : null,
            'description'        => wpautop( do_shortcode( $product->get_description() ) ),
            'short_description'  => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->get_short_description() ),
            'reviews_allowed'    => $product->get_reviews_allowed(),
            'average_rating'     => wc_format_decimal( $product->get_average_rating(), 2 ),
            'rating_count'       => $product->get_rating_count(),
            'related_ids'        => array_map( 'absint', array_values( wc_get_related_products( $product->get_id() ) ) ),
            'upsell_ids'         => array_map( 'absint', $product->get_upsell_ids() ),
            'cross_sell_ids'     => array_map( 'absint', $product->get_cross_sell_ids() ),
            'parent_id'          => $product->get_parent_id(),
            'categories'         => wc_get_object_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat', 'name' ),
            'tags'               => wc_get_object_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_tag', 'name' ),
            'images'             => $this->get_images( $product ),
            'featured_src'       => wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product->get_id() ) ),
            'attributes'         => $this->get_attributes( $product ),
            'downloads'          => $this->get_downloads( $product ),
            'download_limit'     => $product->get_download_limit(),
            'download_expiry'    => $product->get_download_expiry(),
            'download_type'      => 'standard',
            'purchase_note'      => wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $product->get_purchase_note() ) ) ),
            'total_sales'        => $product->get_total_sales(),
            'variations'         => array(),
            'parent'             => array(),
        );
    }
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. It does work partly. This `$this->get_images( $product )` gives me the following error: `Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context`. And I do get the `name` of the category, but I want the `id` and `slug` as well. Is that possible to do that with 1 line of code? This `wc_get_object_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat', 'name', 'id', 'slug' )` does not work for example.

Comment: Copy the `get_images` function from the file and paste in your active theme functions.php and remove `$this` from calling. By default the `wc_get_object_terms` will return `name`, `id`, `slug`

Comment: The categories indeed work now, I had to remove `name` in `wc_get_object_terms`.  But when I remove $this and call the images like this: `get_images($product)`, I get the follow error message: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_images()`